# Pagination with jQuery / AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

What plugin should I use to paginate the output of the below PHP foreach (around 400 `<articles>`):

```
 <div id="hotel-list" class="hotel-list listing-style3 hotel">
 <?php foreach ($hotelName as $index => $name):?>
<article class="box" data-board="<?php echo $board[$index];?>"  data-stars="<?php echo $StarRating[$index];?>" name="<?php echo $hotelName[$index];?>" data-price="<?php $pret1 =$hotelPrices[$index];echo round($pret1 + ($pret1 * 0.20));?>">
    <figure class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
        <a title=""><img width="270" height="160" alt="" src="<?php echo $img[$index][0];?>"></a>
    </figure>
    <div class="details col-sm-7 col-md-8">
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo $name;?><small><i class="soap-icon-departure yellow-color"></i> <?php echo $hotelAddress[$index];?>, <?php echo $hotelDestination[$index];?></small></h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="stars-<?php echo $StarRating[$index];?>-container">
                    <span class="stars-<?php echo $StarRating[$index];?>" style="width: 80%;"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <div>
            <p class="article-text"><label>Perioada: &nbsp;</label> <?php echo $In;?> - <?php echo $Out;?> &nbsp; <?php echo $adults;?> adulti / <?php echo $kids;?> copii; </p>
            <p class="article-text"><label>Tip Masa:&nbsp; </label><?php echo $boardType[$index];?></p>
            <p class="article-text"><label>Camera(e):&nbsp; </label><?php echo $availHotelss[$index]->rooms[0]->roomCategory;?>&nbsp;<?php echo $availHotelss[$index]->rooms[1]->roomCategory;?>&nbsp;<?php echo $availHotelss[$index]->rooms[2]->roomCategory;?>&nbsp;<?php echo $availHotelss[$index]->rooms[3]->roomCategory;?></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="price"><small>De la</small>€<?php $pret1 =$hotelPrices[$index];echo round($pret1 + ($pret1 * 0.2)); ?></span>
                <a class="button btn-small full-width text-center" title="" href="Hotel-Detalii.php?hotel=<?php echo $hotelCodes[$index];?>">DETALII</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<?php endforeach?>
</div>
```

I found only pagination plugin for MYSQL records.

Comment: You are rendering the result on server side. It is not ajax. You should do pagination against database.

Comment: @franziga jQuery is loaded after server side content is returned .   The pagination against database is not suitable for me as all the dynamic content is returned from a API service

Comment: It is not ajax anyway. And it is not a common pagination scenario because your browser already downloads all records in html. I think you need to write your own plugin to hide the records.